# Python setup, install one module as a sub module of another module?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I would like to create a package that installs into a submodule of another python package as an extension.

Basically the original module is set up like so:

```
origmodule/
    __init__.py
    stuff.py
    ext/
        __init__.py
        # This module is empty
```

And then have my extension module installed into the empty origmodule.ext module. Reading the instructions for `distutils` it was not clear if this is possible or supported. The end goal is so that my extension module once installed would be imported like this:

`import origmodule.ext.my_extension`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that with setuptools, installing inside another package is *not* supported.

Instead, you want to use [entry points](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html?highlight=entry%20points#entry-points) instead. Your `origmodule` should look for anything registered as an entry point for a specific key, and your `extension` module should register itself for that key.

Your extension registers an extension point:

```
entry_points={
    'some.opaque.string.unique.to.origmodule':
        ['my_extension = my.extension.package:some.entry.point', ]
}
```

which your `origmodule` then can discover by asking `pkg_resources`:

```
import pkg_resources

for entrypoint in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group='some.opaque.string.unique.to.origmodule'):
    extension = entrypoint.load()
```

Take a look at the [Babel project](http://babel.edgewall.org/) as an example. Babel can extract translatable text from files; it knows how to do this for Python source code, but it also supports extensions that can extract such text from other formats.

Such extraction methods can be registered as extension points. Babel documents this in the  [Writing Extraction Methods](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/messages.html#writing-extraction-methods) section. The message extraction code then [loads those entry points](http://babel.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/babel/messages/extract.py#L259) when extracting text:

```
GROUP_NAME = 'babel.extractors'

# ...

for entry_point in working_set.iter_entry_points(GROUP_NAME,
                                                 method):
    func = entry_point.load(require=True)
    break
```

The [Mako templating language](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/) supplies such a plugin; it [registers the entry point](http://www.makotemplates.org/trac/browser/setup.py#L52), which points to the [actual implementation](http://www.makotemplates.org/trac/browser/mako/ext/babelplugin.py#L13):

```
[babel.extractors]
mako = mako.ext.babelplugin:extract
```

```
def extract(fileobj, keywords, comment_tags, options):
    # ...
```

Comment: I'm not clear, what is `some.opaque.string.unique.to.origmodule`? Is this just a name I choose for let's say extensions, and any third party, or other module can register itself with that name? Second, if so, does this name need to be unique to my application, for example if some other package uses the same name, will that other package try and import my extensions?

Comment: Yes, it's just a name you choose, that is what an opaque string means. :-) If another package uses the same name it'll also load the same entry points, naturally.